# (8)Exec format error: exec of ' /usr/local/download/abc.zip' when access file through apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-auth

I had configure [mod-auth-token](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/) in Apache install on Linux server.
I had configure it to enable security in access file while download from server.( As per given on its [website here](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token)).

Apache configuration :

```
ScriptAlias /downloads/ /usr/local/download/
<Location /downloads/>
  AuthTokenSecret       "SECURESTR"
  AuthTokenPrefix       /downloads/
  AuthTokenTimeout      86400
</Location>
```

I had generate URL for downloading file from server by simple java program ( which is same as example given [here](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/#Java) ).
I have below URL to access file
`http://download.mysite.com/downloads/9fa653c32af806ba6f43d1a1fb73bfd0/5370c3b3/abc.zip`

file `abc.zip` is located at `/usr/local/download/` folder.

When I tried to access / download this file I got the below exception that

```
[Tue May 13 02:07:28 2014] [error] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/local/download/abc.zip' failed
[Tue May 13 02:07:28 2014] [error] Premature end of script headers: abc.zip
```

I don't know what is problem. 
Is anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `ScriptAlias /downloads/ /usr/local/download/`, which tells Apache to run all of the files in /usr/local/download as CGI scripts, instead of just serving them up.  That's why it says `exec of '/usr/local/download/abc.zip' failed`.  See [ScriptAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias).

The solution is to replace `ScriptAlias` by `Alias`.